# Showing that $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \le \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}-\frac k 2 (b-x)$ when $f'' \ge k$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a function of class $C^2$ on $[a,b]$ such that $f'' \ge k$ for $k\in\mathbb{R}$.

The problem is to show that for all $x \in [a,b]$, we have $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \le \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}-\frac k 2 (b-x)$.

I tried Taylor-Lagrange formula but I didn't succeed because of the signs...

I tried to use convex methods but it fails as the condition doesn't imply convexity or concavity (if $k$ is negative, then $f$ isn't necessarly concave).

Is there any idea ?
Thanks in advance.

**NB**:
Conversely, if this inequality holds for all $[c,d] \subset [a,b]$, do we have $f'' \ge k$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

For $ x\in (a,b]$  put

$$g(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$

then, by MVT,

$$g(b)=g(x)+(b-x)\color{red}{g'(c)}$$

with

$$g'(c)=\frac{f'(c)(c-a)-f(c)+f(a)}{(c-a)^2}$$

and, by Taylor-Lagrange formula,

$$f(a)=f(c)+f'(c)(a-c)+\frac{(a-c)^2}{2}f"(d)$$

which gives
$$\color{red}{g'(c)}=\frac 12f"(d)\ge \frac k2$$

thus
$$g(b)\ge g(x)+\frac k2(b-x)$$